# Angular Radio Values in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and am trying to capture the selected radio value but the documentation is not clear when using ng-repeat. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ed">
  <label for="{{item['code']}}">
    <input ng-change="getPlanTypes()" ng-model="ed" type="radio" id="{{item['code']}}" name="effective_date" value="{{item['code']}}">
    {{item['date']}} </label>
</div>
```

Here is the controller but I'm unsure of the right way to get the selected radio value?

```
rates.controller('getEffectiveDates', 
    function($scope, $http, $location, myService, localStorageService) {
        myService.effective_dates().then(function(ed) {
        $scope.ed = ed; 
    });

    $scope.getPlanTypes = function() {
        console.log($scope.ed['code']); //Futile attempt that returns undefined
        localStorageService.add('code',$scope.ed['code']);
        $location.path("/plan-types");
    }       
});
```

Comment: Looks like it should be updating the ng-model based on the value of the selected radio, what if you do this instead: console.log($scope.ed);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
ng-click="getPlanTypes(item.code)"
```

and in your controller, you can get the value

```
$scope.getPlanTypes = function (ed) {
    console.log(ed);
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought too but I tried this in a fiddle and the ng-change only seems to fire once for each radio button when it's clicked but not again when it's clicked later... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2LZpv/

The HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="getEffectiveDates">
<div ng-repeat="item in ed">
  <label for="{{item['code']}}">
      <input ng-click="getPlanTypes(item)" ng-model="ed" type="radio" id="{{item['code']}}" name="effective_date" value="{{item['code']}}"/>
    {{item['date']}} </label>
</div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('getEffectiveDates', ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.ed = [{code:'1',date:"test date 1"},{code:'2',date:"test date 2"}];

    $scope.getPlanTypes = function(selectedItem) {
        console.log(selectedItem["code"]); //Feeble attempt that returns undefined
    }       
}]);
```